# Popout window on mobile using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ecommerce site. On the checkout page there is a link to our Privacy and Cookie Policy.

However, I do not want them to navigate away from the checkout page as I want to try keep them there to continue with the purchase.

So instead of navigating away it opens in a new window, like so:

```
$("#my_link").on("click", function(){
    window.open('my_page.php', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0,width=600,height=800');
});
```

On mobile this will just open in a new tab rather than a new pop out window which is kind of expected, but what I want to know is if there is a better way of doing this that will keep the user at checkout on mobile.

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting to happen other than the default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since You are using jQuery as I saw in your code, you can easily use any of jQuery plugins (or jQuery UI) to have a Modal or Dialog box that loads the content of your `Privacy and Cookie Policy`, I mean once the user clicks on #my_link

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```